# Checkout a new branch without writing current branch commits?

Tags: git, github

I wanted to make a new branch `production` and copy only one latest commit from current branch `develop` to new branch `production`. I created and checked out the branch with command `git checkout -b production`. But when I review the commits with `git log` in `production` branch than instead of getting 0 commits I'm getting all commits from the `develop` branch. I only want one latest commit from develop branch and I don't know how to achieve it. Can anybody help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: 'develop' is a parent branch, hence any branch originated from 'develop' will sustain all commits, you may have to create the brannch from the parent branch of 'develop' and have to write your last commit manually in that new branch,

Comment: Look into using shallow git clones.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's meaningless if you're already on a branch with the full history and creating another branch in the same repository. Branches are just "pointers" after all.

Comment: As suggested by @iBug above, you could try creating a orphan branch and then perform a cherry-pick operation for that single commit.

Comment: @nobalG Ohh I got it. Thanks for information :)

Comment: @iBug Thanks man. That link solved my issue. Sorry I didn't knew that question was already there.

Comment: @Dev-vruper Yes I did that. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

By default, new branch is created from the last commit from current branch. Try this (Specify the commit which you want as the HEAD in the new branch):

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name> <your-commit-id>
```

Comment: I'm still getting all the commits. I just want first commit.